# Do not execute jQuery stored inside array each time function is called

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I currently store a few jQuery snippets inside an array which is stored inside a function. Once I call the function from my codebase, every jQuery snippet is executed. Hence, preventing me from working through the array.

The following code is an example:

```
var remove = [
    jQuery("#mesh option:selected").removeAttr("selected"),
    jQuery("#pipetype option:selected").removeAttr("selected"),
    jQuery("#caboption option:selected").removeAttr("selected"),
    jQuery("#bedsize option:selected").removeAttr("selected"),
    jQuery("#model option:selected").removeAttr("selected"),
    jQuery("#year option:selected").removeAttr("selected"),
];


for (var i = 0; i <= amount; i++) {
    remove[i];
}
```

How can I assure that when `deselect()` is called, that only a few array elements get executed instead all of them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. The array elements execute when you declare it self.

Instead of everything you can just do

```
var remove = [ "mesh","pipetype", "caboption","bedsize", "model","year"];
for (var i = 0; i <= amount; i++) {
   jQuery("#"+remove[i]+" option:selected").removeAttr("selected"),
}
```

---

If you do not have any other select boxes apart from these, you could also simply do

```
$("select option").prop("selected", false);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want them to be executed immediately, make it an array of functions, and call them in the loop with `()`.

```
var remove = [
    () => jQuery("#mesh option:selected").removeAttr("selected"),
    () => jQuery("#pipetype option:selected").removeAttr("selected"),
    () => jQuery("#caboption option:selected").removeAttr("selected"),
    () => jQuery("#bedsize option:selected").removeAttr("selected"),
    () => jQuery("#model option:selected").removeAttr("selected"),
    () => jQuery("#year option:selected").removeAttr("selected"),
];


for (var i = 0; i <= amount; i++) {
    remove[i]();
}
```